# Enter parameter value but I've already included one in the query

Tags: ms-access, select, vb6, inner-join

I've got a SQL query in my `VB6` project that is performing a three-way `INNER JOIN` in an `Ms-Access` database.

The `VB6` query is:

```
SQL = "SELECT popsLines.stockCode, popsLines.orderNumber, popsOrders.dateOrdered, popsReceipts.dateReceived, popsReceipts.reference" & _
            " FROM (popsOrders INNER JOIN popsLines ON popsOrders.orderNumber = popsLines.orderNumber)" & _
            " INNER JOIN popsReceipts ON popsOrders.orderNumber = popsReceipts.orderNumber" & _
            " WHERE (([WHERE popsLines].[stockCode]=" & sqlString(m_sStockCode) & "));"
```

This wasn't working, it returned an error saying

> No value given for one or more required parameters

So then next thing I did was copy the value in the SQL variable and paste it into an Access query, with the value of the `m_sStockCode` parameter.

```
SELECT popsLines.stockCode, popsLines.orderNumber, popsOrders.dateOrdered, popsReceipts.dateReceived, popsReceipts.reference 
FROM (popsOrders INNER JOIN popsLines ON popsOrders.orderNumber = popsLines.orderNumber)
INNER JOIN popsReceipts ON popsOrders.orderNumber = popsReceipts.orderNumber WHERE (([WHERE popsLines].[stockCode]="010010003"));
```

When executing this, it said

> Enter Parameter Value: WHERE popsLines.StockCode

Why isn't it accepting the query as it is?

I've also tried changing there `WHERE`clause to

```
(( WHERE [popsLines].[stockCode]="010010003"));
```

but got

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((WHERE [popsLines].[stockCode]="010010003"))'

Comment: The where clause should be `WHERE (([popsLines].[stockCode]="010010003"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part - your WHERE clause - is garbled. It should read:

```
.. WHERE ([popsLines].[stockCode]='010010003');
```